# Ember simple auth how to update when authenticate data is avaiable

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-simple-auth

Ember app is using adfs login.
when a successful login adfs will redirect to ember web app with a route and query parameters. those query parameters contain

```
access_token
refresh_token
user_id
scope
```

i need to update session of the ember auth with those credential data. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to `authenticate` a session with you **params**.
In order to being able to authenticate your session you will need to create an **authenticator**. Basically, this will provide you some method to being able to handle your session (`invalidateSession`, `authenticate`, `restoreSession` etc..).
For the authenticator creation check out http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthenticator.html
It will look like something like so https://jsfiddle.net/e7nzoa6y/ **but that's not exclusive you will have to custom it** with you endpoint and stuff

Then once you have your authenticator, check out the doc at 
http://ember-simple-auth.com/api/classes/BaseAuthenticator.html

In your controller, after injecting the `session` service,
you will be able to call the function authenticate with something looking like

```
this.session.authenticate(
  'authenticator:YOUR_AUTHENTICATOR', queryParams
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[djamel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6156142/djamel)  your answer works for me and i have modified the code using your example as below

```
import Base from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/base';
import {
  isEmpty
} from '@ember/utils';
export default Base.extend({
  authenticate(data) {
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

       if(data.access_token!=null){
       resolve({

                     access_token: data.access_token,
                     id: data.id,
                     agreement:data.agreement
                   });
   }else{
    reject();
   }  })

  },

 restore(data) {
   console.log(data)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      if (!isEmpty(data.access_token)) {
        resolve(data);
      } else {
        reject();
      }    });
  }
});
```

other than that i had to add

> ENV['ember-simple-auth'] = {
>             routeAfterAuthentication: 'authenticated.index'
>         },

in config environment as well.